# Cordova: Some input files use or override a deprecated API

Tags: android, cordova

I've checked for the same query in SO but nothing was worked for me. While i'm trying to run the app (by using `cordova run android`). I'm getting following errors

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:font
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontStyle
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontWeight
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:ttcIndex


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

For this i got one suggestion to mention the `compileSdkVersion` in `plugin.xml`. According to this suggestion I've mentioned

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="23" android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

but again I'm facing the same problem. Can any one know what's the problem and how to solve it

**Edit**

```
      <!--dependencies-->
      <framework src="libs/plugin.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference"/>
      <framework src="com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1" />
      <framework src="commons-io:commons-io:2.4" />
      <framework src="com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3" />
```

Comment: what plugins do you have installed?

Comment: @jcesarmobile Thank you very much for assisting me every time!!!:-)

I'm using custom plugin, that have voice recording capability but i'm unable to post that code here....

Comment: is your plugin using some Android support library?

Comment: Plz check my edit for plugin.xml file

Comment: Try changing `<framework src="com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1" />` to `<framework src="com.android.support:support-v4:27.+" />`

Comment: In this way also i'm getting the same problem

Comment: and your project only have this plugin? Ah, and don't set the targetSdkVersion="23", that's too old, use 27 too (or don't set any and let Cordova use the one it's configured to use)

Comment: Yes I've only this plugin and I removed sdk version. Then also I'm getting same problem